# Lookup values based solely on minumum value of range

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm wanting to place values within a range given only a minimum value, similar to using a VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP in Excel using the "FALSE" criteron.

As seen below, TableScore lists the low-end cutpoints (CutpointVal) for a value to be assigned a specific number of points (the minimum value in a range). The below SQL code accomplishes this in two steps, with the first query generating a datasheet that includes a high value for each low value, thus creating a full range.

However, this is a somewhat clunky way of doing this, especially when trying to iterate this many times. **The original table (TableScore) cannot be altered to include high values.** Is there a way to accomplish a similar mechanism with only one query?

Main

```
ID              Score
72625           2.5
78261           3.2
82766           4.7
58383           0.3
```

TableScore

```
CutpointVal     Points
0               0
0.3             1
1.2             2
2.7             3
3.4             4
```

Upper and lower range query (RangeQry):

```
SELECT a.CutpointVal AS LowVal, Val(Nz((SELECT TOP 1 [CutpointVal]-0.001
FROM TableScore b
WHERE b.Points > a.Points
ORDER BY b.Points ASC),9999)) AS HighVal, a.Points
FROM TableScore AS a
ORDER BY a.Points;
```

Range assignment query:

```
SELECT Main.ID, Main.Score, RangeQry.LowVal, RangeQry.HighVal, RangeQry.Points AS PTS
FROM RangeQry, Main
WHERE (((Main.Score) Between [RangeQry].[LowVal] And [RangeQry].[HighVal]));
```

Desired output:

```
ID        Score        Points
72625     2.5          2
78261     3.2          3
82766     4.7          4
58383     0.3          1
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data table and well as desired output.

Comment: Update added @June7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Main.ID, Main.Score, (
    SELECT Max(Points) FROM TableScore WHERE CutpointVal<=Main.Score) AS Pts
FROM Main;
```

Or

```
SELECT Main.ID, Main.Score, (
    SELECT TOP 1 Points FROM TableScore 
    WHERE CutpointVal <= Main.Score 
    ORDER BY Points DESC) AS Pts
FROM Main;
```

Or

```
SELECT Main.ID, Main.Score, DMax("Points","TableScore","CutpointVal<=" & [Score]) AS Pts
FROM Main;
```